# ReactiveX how to pause observable

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-programming, reactivex

I'm using [ReactiveX](http://reactivex.io/) in iOS/Swift ([RxSwift](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift)).

Let's say I have an observable:

```
let dataUpdates = ...
```

Which I'm subscribed to:

```
dataUpdates.subscribeNext({ data in
    // update tableView with data
    // maybe move to a difference cell with an animation
})
```

If I received an update while I'm animating, I don't want to receive the next update until the animation finishes (I don't want to loose the updates that happen during the animation either).

So all I need is to pause the emitting of that `dataUpdates` observable.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: This question is old but maybe you have not found an answer to it yet.

Unless your Observable supports backpressure(in other way than dropping emissions after certain threshold) handling and you cannot simply stop emissions from entering that observable there is nothing more you can do(afaik) as reactive programming is push based rather than pull(backpressure is a pull mechanism).

Comment: I Implemented a `subscribeNextAndWait` which solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Use BehaviorSubject to create a valve that pauses and resumes the updates. Note that you will then need some backpressure support (i.e. buffering) in `dataUpdates` for the updates that arrive when the valve is closed.

So in pseudo code (I don't code switft, so excuse my syntax)

```
// create a BehaviorSubject with default value true. It will always emit
// the latest value when subscribed to, thus it is kind of a variable
let valve = BehaviorSubject(value: true)

// we are only interested to get one `true` value. When the latest value
// received by the valve is `true`, this will give a value immediately when
// subscribed to. When the latest value is `false`, this will not give
// any events until it is true.
let openValve = valve.filter{$0}.take(1)

// for each data update, pass it through if the valve is open and otherwise
// start waiting for it to turn true
let pauseableDataUpdates = dataUpdates.concatMap{update in openValve.map { _ in update}}

// now when you start rendering, you do
valve.on(.Next(false))

// and after animation is done, you do
valve.on(.Next(true))
```